# navigation for superscrollorama

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i'm using  superscrollorama http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/ is posible to create in some way a navigation , i can not find any way to create , i'm using scrollTo plugin , but it scrolls just one section and then it stops . what shall i do ?
Thank You a Lot for Helping

Here is javascript code :

```
$('.menu li a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        pieces = $this.attr('class').split('m_');

    if(typeof pieces[1] != "undefined"){
        var section = $('body').find('#'+pieces[1]);
        var pos = section.position();

        $(window).scrollTo(pos.top, 2500, {queue:true});
    }
});
```

Thank you a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

I did not use superscroll for navigation I just used jquery animate.

```
`// Scroll
$('a.scroll').click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
scroll($(this).attr("href"));
});`

`// LINKS
function scroll(link){
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(link).offset().top - 0}, 'slow');
}`
```

Please note you may need to include your links code in a jquery on ready function.